# how to set css position absolute in hover state

Tags: html, css, hover, position

CSS position not working properly on `div` section, i want to enlarge div on mouse hover and `div` section should overlapped on other section, but not working properly [**FIDDLE LINK**](http://jsbin.com/kumetovimito/1/)

Code
**HTML**

```
<body>
<div class="block-div">
    <div class="card-box first-child">
        <div class="card-box-in">
            <div class="card-image"> 
                <img alt="img" src="https://mtgostock.com/contents/cards/thumbs/157x157/en/isd/105.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="card-info"> 
                <ul class="bgpupulcards">
                    <li class="text-center"> 
                        <a title="Canyon Minotaur, M14 C" href="https://127.0.0.1/mtgostock/card/Canyon-Minotaur-M14-C-77"> Canyon Minotaur... </a>
                        <span> Price: $70.00</span> 
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="searhbg2 SCartaddBTN"> 
                            <a href="#" data-qstring="">Add To Cart</a>
                        </div>
                    </li> 
                </ul> 
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="card-in-hover">
            <div class="card-right-sec">
                <ul class="bgpupulcards"> 
                    <li class="text-hover">
                        <p> Available Quantity: 2 </p> 
                        <div class="half"> <p> Rarity: <span> C </span> </p> </div>
                        <div class="half"> <p> Set: <span> M14 </span></p> </div>
                        <p> User: <span class="blue"> girishs </span> </p>
                        <p> Seller Status: <span> Verified </span></p>
                    </li>
                </ul> 
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="card-box first-child">
        <div class="card-box-in">
            <div class="card-image"> 
                <img alt="img" src="https://mtgostock.com/contents/cards/thumbs/157x157/en/mm/324.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="card-info"> 
                <ul class="bgpupulcards">
                    <li class="text-center"> 
                        <a title="Canyon Minotaur, M14 C" href="https://127.0.0.1/mtgostock/card/Canyon-Minotaur-M14-C-77"> Canyon Minotaur... </a>
                        <span> Price: $70.00</span> 
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="searhbg2 SCartaddBTN"> 
                            <a href="#" data-qstring="">Add To Cart</a>
                        </div>
                    </li> 
                </ul> 
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="card-in-hover">
            <div class="card-right-sec">
                <ul class="bgpupulcards"> 
                    <li class="text-hover">
                        <p> Available Quantity: 2 </p> 
                        <div class="half"> <p> Rarity: <span> C </span> </p> </div>
                        <div class="half"> <p> Set: <span> M14 </span></p> </div>
                        <p> User: <span class="blue"> girishs </span> </p>
                        <p> Seller Status: <span> Verified </span></p>
                    </li>
                </ul> 
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="card-box first-child">
        <div class="card-box-in">
            <div class="card-image"> 
                <img alt="img" src="https://mtgostock.com/contents/cards/thumbs/157x157/en/vma/4.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="card-info"> 
                <ul class="bgpupulcards">
                    <li class="text-center"> 
                        <a title="Canyon Minotaur, M14 C" href="https://127.0.0.1/mtgostock/card/Canyon-Minotaur-M14-C-77"> Canyon Minotaur... </a>
                        <span> Price: $70.00</span> 
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="searhbg2 SCartaddBTN"> 
                            <a href="#" data-qstring="">Add To Cart</a>
                        </div>
                    </li> 
                </ul> 
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="card-in-hover">
            <div class="card-right-sec">
                <ul class="bgpupulcards"> 
                    <li class="text-hover">
                        <p> Available Quantity: 2 </p> 
                        <div class="half"> <p> Rarity: <span> C </span> </p> </div>
                        <div class="half"> <p> Set: <span> M14 </span></p> </div>
                        <p> User: <span class="blue"> girishs </span> </p>
                        <p> Seller Status: <span> Verified </span></p>
                    </li>
                </ul> 
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="card-box first-child">
        <div class="card-box-in">
            <div class="card-image"> 
                <img alt="img" src="https://mtgostock.com/contents/cards/thumbs/157x157/en/isd/105.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="card-info"> 
                <ul class="bgpupulcards">
                    <li class="text-center"> 
                        <a title="Canyon Minotaur, M14 C" href="https://127.0.0.1/mtgostock/card/Canyon-Minotaur-M14-C-77"> Canyon Minotaur... </a>
                        <span> Price: $70.00</span> 
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="searhbg2 SCartaddBTN"> 
                            <a href="#" data-qstring="">Add To Cart</a>
                        </div>
                    </li> 
                </ul> 
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="card-in-hover">
            <div class="card-right-sec">
                <ul class="bgpupulcards"> 
                    <li class="text-hover">
                        <p> Available Quantity: 2 </p> 
                        <div class="half"> <p> Rarity: <span> C </span> </p> </div>
                        <div class="half"> <p> Set: <span> M14 </span></p> </div>
                        <p> User: <span class="blue"> girishs </span> </p>
                        <p> Seller Status: <span> Verified </span></p>
                    </li>
                </ul> 
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.card-box{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #C7C7C9;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #E9E9E9;
    min-height: 300px;
    float: left;
    margin: 15px;
}
.card-box-in{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #eaeaec;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 283px;
    margin: 8px;
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
}
.card-box:hover{
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
}
.card-box:hover .card-box-in{
    margin-right: 0;
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
.card-box-in .card-image{
    padding-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.card-in-hover{
    display: none;
    width: 149px;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #eaeaec;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 283px;
    margin: 8px;
    float: left;
}
.card-box:hover .card-in-hover{
    display: block;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}
.card-in-hover .card-right-sec{
    border-left: 1px solid #A4A4A4;
    height: 260px;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
ul.bgpupulcards{ 
    color: #004395;
    display: block;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 148px;
}
.block_wrapper-shadow { width:100%; text-align:center;}
ul.bgpupulcards li.text-center{
    text-align: center;
}
ul.bgpupulcards li a{font-weight:bolder; color:#004395; line-height:21px;}
ul.bgpupulcards li a:hover{ text-decoration:none;}
ul.bgpupulcards li span{ color:#39b54a; font-weight: 700;}

ul.bgpupulcards li.text-hover p { font-size:12px; color:#6b6b6b;  width:187px; padding-left:13px; padding-top:4px; padding-bottom:4px; width:140px;}
ul.bgpupulcards li.text-hover p span { color:#39b54a;} 
ul.bgpupulcards li.text-hover p span.blue { color:#00aeef;} 
.searhbg2{ background:url(../../images/v2.0/searchbg.png) no-repeat left top;  width:122px; height:46px; font-size:12px; float:left; color:#fff; text-align:center; line-height:40px; margin:5px 0px 5px 13px;}

.searhbg2 a { color:#fff!important; font-weight:normal!important; padding-left:0!important;}
```

**Expected result**

[image]

How to setup position absolute of section by CSS, i tried so far but not success.

Please help to me how to figure out section over state.

Thank you

Comment: If you relly want it to be an absolute, than add a warpper around each element and set it to `relative` position. Or you can just apply bigger z-index to the element on hover and styled it properly.

Comment: @drip i tried that.. but not working me, can it possible by CSS?

Comment: Yep you will have to change a little your css. The most outer div must have a width set (a.k.a the `.card-box` divs). The inside one should hold the border and background and on hover you can set it's width... Something on those lines. Or you can mask it with the hover half by making absolute and adding border to it... There are a few possibilities.

Comment: @drip i am not expert in css, but let me try your way.. thanks

Comment: Here is what I mean: http://jsbin.com/jiwadobufahi/1/ (there should be a few other tweaks on the height, but you get the point)

Comment: @drip amazing.. working well as expected thanks

Comment: You could potentially add the hover content to the current item and just make it bigger.. http://jsbin.com/kumetovimito/4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exact result porivde by @drip

**HTML**

```
<div class="block-div">
    <div class="card-box first-child">
        <div class="card-box-in">
            <div class="card-image"> 
                <img alt="img" src="https://mtgostock.com/contents/cards/thumbs/157x157/en/isd/105.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="card-info"> 
                <ul class="bgpupulcards">
                    <li class="text-center"> 
                        <a title="Canyon Minotaur, M14 C" href="https://127.0.0.1/mtgostock/card/Canyon-Minotaur-M14-C-77"> Canyon Minotaur... </a>
                        <span> Price: $70.00</span> 
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="searhbg2 SCartaddBTN"> 
                            <a href="#" data-qstring="">Add To Cart</a>
                        </div>
                    </li> 
                </ul> 
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="card-in-hover">
            <div class="card-right-sec">
                <ul class="bgpupulcards"> 
                    <li class="text-hover">
                        <p> Available Quantity: 2 </p> 
                        <div class="half"> <p> Rarity: <span> C </span> </p> </div>
                        <div class="half"> <p> Set: <span> M14 </span></p> </div>
                        <p> User: <span class="blue"> girishs </span> </p>
                        <p> Seller Status: <span> Verified </span></p>
                    </li>
                </ul> 
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {background: url(../../images/v2.0/pettarn.jpg) left top repeat;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 0 0 0px;
    font:12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

a{color:#9b0000; text-decoration:none; outline:none;}
a:hover{text-decoration:underline;}

.floatleft{ float:left !important;}
.floatright{ float:right !important;}

.rt{text-align:right !important;}
.lt{text-align:left !important;}
.jt{text-align:justify !important;}
.ct{text-align:center !important;}

.full{width:100%; float:left;}
.half{width:50%; float:left;}
.clear{clear:both;}
.display{display:inline-block;}
.position { position:relative;}

p, input, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, ul, li{padding:0; margin:0; outline:none; list-style:none; font-weight:normal;}

img{border:0; outline:none;}
.font0{font-size:0px;}
strong{font-weight:bold;}

h1{ font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif; font-size:25px; width:100%; color:#da74b3; line-height:25px; padding:35px 0 15px 0;} 
h2 { font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif; font-size:30px; text-transform:uppercase; width:100%; text-align:center; padding-top:35px; padding-bottom:25px; color:#FFF;}
/*h3 { font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif; font-size:18px; text-transform:uppercase; width:100%; color:#da74b3; line-height:25px; min-height:45px; vertical-align: middle;}*/
h1 img, 
h4 img { margin-right:18px; float:left;}
h4 { border-bottom:#e6e6e6 solid 1px;}
h4 img { margin-left:10px;}
.card-box{
    position: relative;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #C7C7C9;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #E9E9E9;
    min-height: 300px;
    float: left;
    margin: 15px;
    width: 165px;
}
.card-box-in{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #eaeaec;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 283px;
    margin: 8px;
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
}
.card-box:hover{
    z-index: 2;
}
.card-box:hover .card-box-in{
    margin-right: 0;
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
.card-box-in .card-image{
    padding-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.card-in-hover{
    display: none;
    width: 149px;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #eaeaec;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    border: 8px solid #C7C7C9;
    border-left: 0;
    height: 283px;
    margin: 0 0 0 -16px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:100%;
}
.card-box:hover .card-in-hover{
    display: block;

}
.card-in-hover .card-right-sec{
    border-left: 1px solid #A4A4A4;
    height: 260px;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
ul.bgpupulcards{ 
    color: #004395;
    display: block;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 148px;
}
.block_wrapper-shadow { width:100%; text-align:center;}
ul.bgpupulcards li.text-center{
    text-align: center;
}
ul.bgpupulcards li a{font-weight:bolder; color:#004395; line-height:21px;}
ul.bgpupulcards li a:hover{ text-decoration:none;}
ul.bgpupulcards li span{ color:#39b54a; font-weight: 700;}

ul.bgpupulcards li.text-hover p { font-size:12px; color:#6b6b6b;  width:187px; padding-left:13px; padding-top:4px; padding-bottom:4px; width:140px;}
ul.bgpupulcards li.text-hover p span { color:#39b54a;} 
ul.bgpupulcards li.text-hover p span.blue { color:#00aeef;} 
.searhbg2{ background:url(../../images/v2.0/searchbg.png) no-repeat left top;  width:122px; height:46px; font-size:12px; float:left; color:#fff; text-align:center; line-height:40px; margin:5px 0px 5px 13px;}

.searhbg2 a { color:#fff!important; font-weight:normal!important; padding-left:0!important;}
```